# "Reflection": Method with "params" does not initialize my custom Objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom class from which I create over 200 objects for a Gui.
In my main class with my business logic I want to apply the instantiation of all my objects, attach them to an event handler and set their Name. Instead of doing all this by hand for every object I thought to create a method that takes as parameters a "params" list of my objects. The problem is that this method seems to work out a "copy" of my objects instead the reference of those. What I have so far is:

My object base class:

```
public class MyObject
{
  ... // this works
}
```

My business class now (what works):

```
public class Logic
{
  public MyObject Object001, Object002,... Object200; // note that they are not instantiated yet

  public Logic()
  {

    Object001 = new MyObject();
    Object001.Name = nameof(Object001);
    Object001.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));

    Object002 = new MyObject();
    Object002.Name = nameof(Object002);
    Object002.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));

    ...

    Object200 = new MyObject();
    Object200.Name = nameof(Object200 );
    Object200.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));

  }
}
```

My desired business class (what has not worked):

```
public class Logic
{
  public MyObject Object001, Object002,... Object200; // note that they are not instantiated yet

  public Logic()
  {
    InstantiateAllObjects(Object001, Object002, ..., Object200); // here my 200 objects!
  }

  private void InstantiateAllObjects(params MyObject[] list)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
    {         
      // if(list[i]==Object001) Console.WriteLine("Object001== null?: " + (Object001 == null)); --> this executes for EVERY object, instead for only Object001!!

      MyObject obj = list[i];
      obj = new MyObject();
      obj.Name = nameof(obj); //  why "nameof(list[i])" didn't work?
      obj.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));

      // if (list[i] == Object001) Console.WriteLine("Object001== null?: " + (Object001== null)); --> this executes again for EVERY object AND (Object001== null) is ALWAYS true!!
    }
  }

}
```

Can anybody explain me why my method seems not to create my objects?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

**EDIT**

In my opinion, the problem seems to be i have to pass a reference to these declared objects in the 'params' list of my method... is it possible? how? I tried to use the modifiers "out" and "ref" near the "params" in the method, but with "params" seems not to be possible...

**EDIT2**

Following some suggestions I created in my `class: logic` an object list:

```
MyObject[] list = new MyObject[] { Object001, Object002, ..., Object200 };
InstantiateAllObjects(ref list);
```

and modified my method as per `private void InstantiateAllObjects(ref MyObject[] list)` iterating inside over `list[i]`, but unfortunately with the same wrong result...

and also tried

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>() { Object001, Object002, ..., Object200 };
InstantiateAllObjects(ref list);
```

and modified my method as per `private void InstantiateAllObjects(ref List<MyObject> list)` iterating inside over `list[i]`, but unfortunately also with the same wrong result...

Comment: It won't even compile as you didn't declare `i` variable

Comment: A class with 200 fields seems to to far too much, IMHO.

Comment: sorry, it is a copy-paste failure... otherwise I could not even knew what the Console.WriteLine said, right? ;-) I have already edited...

Comment: `nameof(list[i]`)  just returns `"list[i]"`, not what this actually refers to.

Comment: ^^ As above.  You need to use `list[i].Name`.

Comment: Instead of 200 individual objects, why not use a List or Array of that amount? You will still need to initialize every one though, but at least you can use a simple for-loop for that

Comment: 200 objects all of the same type? Use a List or a Dictionary, where your key can be the name of the object, if you need that.

Comment: `MyObject obj = list[i];` - that assignment is useless, it will be overwritten by the next line `obj = new MyObject();`. It does *not* create a relation between that object you create and any location in the array

Comment: @HansKeﬆing 'obj = new MyObject()' instantiates 'obj' because at the very top of my class 'logic' objects are declared (without instantiation): i need to have them there  because need to be "seen" by other classes that inherit from 'class: logic'

Comment: @anna My remark was about the `=list[i]` part, I know that you need to create a new object here. It just will not end up in the list (it is available for garbage collection on the next iteration through the loop) and even if it did, you will not fill the original class-level field.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing can you please see my EDIT2?

Comment: @anna as others have already said, I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. I think your problem is not the initialization of 200 fields, but rather the problem is that you have 200 fields. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow it doesn't matter if i have 200 or 2 objects, my concern is summarized as per _how can i pass my objects or a list of them as reference_ to a handy method...

Comment: @anna: And the answer is "You can't" - at least, not without declaring each parameter separately as a ref parameter. (That's where it *does* matter whether you have 200 or 2 fields - declaring a method with 2 parameters is reasonable. Declaring a method with 200 parameters is not.) I also *suspect* that the `nameof` operator doesn't do what you think it does. What do you expect the values of the `Name` properties of your object to be? At the moment they're *all* be "obj".

Answer (score 1):

Forget about all those `Object001`, `Object002` etc fields. Just use a `new List<MyObject>()` and add your objects into it inside the for-loop in your `InstantiateAllObjects`.

```
public class Logic
{
  private readonly List<MyObject> allMyObjects; // note that they still are not instantiated yet

  public Logic()
  {
    cont int amount = 200;
    allMyObjects = new List<MyObject>(amount); // reserve space, but all are still null
    InstantiateAllObjects(allMyObjects, amount);
  }

  private void InstantiateAllObjects(List<MyObject> list, int amount)
  {
    for (int i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {         
      MyObject obj = new MyObject();
      obj.Name = "Object" + (i+1).ToString("000"); 
      obj.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));

      list.Add(obj); // place the newly created object in the list
    }
  }

}
```

Your original test `if(list[i]==Object001)` fires every time, because both `list[i]` (for every i) and `Object001` are null.

Also note that you can have multiple references to one instance of your MyObject (this already happens when you pass the reference as parameter to some method). The fact that one of those is called "Object001" is not important and in fact unknown to the instance. That is why `nameof(list[i])` cannot return "Object001".

Comment: But declaring my objects inside `logic` lets them "invisible" to be directly seen from other classes that inheritate from `logic` ... that's why I started declaring them outside and instantiating them inside... do you see any way to still do this?

Comment: @anna: At this point it's very, very unclear what you're trying to achieve. But having 200 separately-declared variables like this is almost *certainly* not the best approach.

Comment: i really need to have the objects declared outside my class `logic`, because there are other classes that inherit from `logic` and I do not want to use setters/getters or anything else, just consume these objects "naturally". Therefore my concern is _how can i pass my objects or a list of them as reference_ to a handy method that takes care of the initialisation process...

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing `allMyObjects` in `InstantiateAllObjects` should be `list` or the parameter can be removed. But as it looks like, anna wants to implement the function outside the Logic class and therefore needs the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Another try, based on Hans Keﬆing'a answer and anna's statement

> 2) the name of every object will be (very) different one to another,
>   it is here just that i used the indexes 001...200 to concept the idea,

To avoid any trouble with accessing the fields and to regard what you wrote in the comments, no getter/setter is used and everything is public. Not the best approach but well, compared to handling 200 separate objects...

```
public class Logic
{
    public List<MyObject> MyObjectList;
    public List<string> MyObjectNames;
    public Logic()
    {
        var anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
        MyObjectNames = new List<string>() {"Object01", "Object02", "Object03"}; // either add your names here...
        MyObjectNames.Add("Object04");  // or add additional names this way
        //MyObjectNames.AddRange(anotherNameList);  // or add another list or use Linq or whatever
        MyObjectList = anotherClass.InstantiateAllObjects(MyObjectNames);
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public List<MyObject> InstantiateAllObjects(List<string> nameList)
    {
        var objectList = new List<MyObject>(nameList.Count);
        foreach (var name in nameList)
        {
          objectList.Add(new MyObject(){Name = name});
        }
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

Does this meet your requirements?

---

If you prefer a Dictionary, it's similar:

```
public class Logic
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyObjectDict;
    public List<string> MyObjectNames;
    public Logic()
    {
        var anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
        MyObjectNames = new List<string>() { "Object01", "Object02", "Object03" }; // either add your names here...
        MyObjectNames.Add("Object04");  // or add additional names this way
        //MyObjectNames.AddRange(anotherNameList);  // or add another list or use Linq or whatever
        MyObjectDict = anotherClass.InstantiateAllObjects(MyObjectNames);
        // objects in dict can be accessed directly by their names:
        var object01 = MyObjectDict["Object01"];
    }
}

// You can access in derived classes or any other classes
public class DerivedLogic : Logic
{
    public void SomeFunc()
    {
        var object01 = MyObjectDict["Object01"];
    }
    public void SomeOtherFunc(string objectName)
    {
        var object01 = MyObjectDict[objectName];
    }
} 

public class AnotherClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, MyObject> InstantiateAllObjects(List<string> nameList)
    {
        var objectList = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>(nameList.Count);
        foreach (var name in nameList)
        {
            // check if object with name does not already exist.
            if(!objectList.ContainsKey(name)
            {
                // For your property changed assignment, you can separate the object creation and DIctionary/List assignment
                var obj = new MyObject() { Name = name };
                obj.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
                objectList.Add(name, obj);
            }
            // else .... doe something
        }
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but although your proposal has introduced an interesting approach, doesn't solve my issue thus as exposed, i need to have objects declared outside my class `Logic` to have them directly visible for other classes that inherit from this class; with your approach I will need to address every object as an index in the list of searching by its given `Name`

Comment: @anna Would it help to have a Dictionary instead of a list? In a Dictionary you can access your objects by their name.
Like `myObjectsDictionary["Object001"]`. I could just modify the example if that helps. Visibility to derived classes is always given for the name list and also for the Dictionary. You can also have the name list just temporary as you can get it easily from the Dictionary itself.

Comment: uhm... unfortunately this would also not be a solution for me in this situation... I need (or really _would like_) to have my objects accessed from the inheriting classes in a _natural way_, that is for example `Object056.Property = (...)` instead of `MyObjectDict[object["Name"].Property = (...)`. I think the way to keep trying on would be `reflection`, but it is still too new to me... thanks for your trials anyway!

Answer (score 0):

All of those arguments are being passed by value. You're passing the references, but the `InstantiateAllObjects` method can't change the values of any of the fields.

Simplifying this a bit, it's a little like having code like this:

```
string x = "Original value";

// This copies the value of x into the array
string[] array = new string[] { x };

// This changes the array element, but doesn't affect the x variable at all
array[0] = "Different value";

// Still prints "Original value", because x hasn't changed
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

As noted in comments, using a list is likely to be a *much* better approach than lots of different fields here.

Comment: if i use a list, i will then need to declare first all of them (200 times) AND later add them all to the list; with my though of the method 'InstantiateAllObjects' i want to spare this second step... in my opinion, the problem seems to be i have to pass a reference to these declared objects in the 'params' list of my method... is it possible? how?

Comment: I tried to use the modifiers "out" and "ref" near the "params" in the method, but with "params" seems not to be possible...

Comment: How about providing an empty List to `InstantiateAllObjects`?
Just filling the List in your `InstantiateAllObjects` function should do what you want.

Comment: @Mihaeru and JonSteek, can you please see my EDIT2?

Comment: @anna Just saw your question and EDIT2 and when I created an example, Hans Keﬆing already posted his :)
Just use what he proposed in his answer.

Comment: @Mihaeru declaring my objects inside logic lets them "invisible" to be directly seen from other classes that inheritate from logic ... that's why I started declaring them outside and instantiating them inside... do you see any way to still do this?

Comment: @anna: You can declare *one* variable - a list - and then populate it in `InstantiateAllObjects`.

Comment: @anna you can handle the list the same way as the separated objects. Just create a public getter or implement your list as protected if you just need to handle it in derived classes.

Comment: thanks, but i really need to have the objects declared outside my class `logic`, because there are other classes that inherit from logic and I do not want to use setters/getters or anything else, just consume these objects "naturally". Therefore my concern is how can i pass my objects or a list of them as reference to a handy method that takes care of the initialisation process...

Comment: I don't see the problem. You can declare the objects wherever you want. You can also make the `allMyObjects` list public. I just saw in Hans Keﬆing, that he adds each created object to `allMyObjects`. Just replace this with `list`. Then the method could be anywhere. If you really, really want, you can also assign the list items after instantiation to your single objects in the Logic class but this makes no sense at all, is much too much effort and will sooner or later for sure result in bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class (can be the same as the one with the logic) to hold your MyObject Fields, pass it into a function that uses reflection to populate the fields.

```
    // Class with Fields
    public class MyObjectCollection
    {
        public MyObject Object001;
        public MyObject ObjTwo;
    }

    public class Logic
    {
        // Init logic
        public void Initialise(object controls)
        {
            Type targType = typeof(MyObject);
            var t = controls.GetType();
            // iterate all fields of type MyObject
            foreach(var fi in t.GetFields().Where(f=>f.FieldType == targType))
            {
                // initialise as required.
                var o = new MyObject();
                o.Name = fi.Name;
                fi.SetValue(controls, o);
            }
        }
    }
```

If the field name is not enough for the object name you could use Attributes on the fields to direct initialisation.

Comment: What happens if `Object042` is of a type that does not contain a public parameterless constructor?

Comment: thanks, but (1) all objects are of the same type `MyObject`, (2) the name of every object will be (very) different one to another, it is here just that i used the indexes 001...200 to concept the idea, and (3) i really need to have the objects declared outside my class `logic`, because there are other classes that inherit from `logic` and I do not want to use setters/getters or anything else, just consume these objects "naturally". Therefore my concern is how can i pass my objects or a list of them as reference to a handy method that takes care of the initialisation process...

Comment: It will fail, short of getting into dependency injection there has to be some known element to the objects.

Comment: can you elaborate please on this? sorry, i didn't get your point...

Comment: Now I understand what you're trying to do. why not use reflection to iterate through all the fields of type MyObject instantiating and initialising them. you wont need to pass any argument into your function and increasing the number objects just requires adding another field

Comment: this code did unfortunately not worked for me... I am very very new to c# and in particular to reflection, and although the code compiled it didn't create my objects nor assigned names, as well as there is not present the event creation... On the other hand, having an extra class to initially declare my objects makes my program structure at the first sight not possible, thus i have some other classes that inherit from my class `Logic` and now they don't "see" my objects... sorry for being all this so complicated, and thanks anyway for your trials!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. It is a reflection-based approach and what it does is:

1. find all public instance fields
2. use only those whose name contains `Object`
3. create a new instance of `MyObject` and store that in the field

---

```
public void InstantiateAllObjects()
{
    foreach (FieldInfo field in this.GetType()
                                    .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Object")))
    {
        MyObject obj= new MyObject();
        obj.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));

        field.SetValue(this, obj);
    }
}
```

---

If you add above method to your `Logic` class, you can then call it without having to explicitly pass `Object001`, `Object002` etc. to it.

```
public class Logic
{
    public MyObject Object001, Object002, ... Object200;

    public Logic()
    {
        this.InstantiateAllObjects();
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT: Differently named fields

If the fields do not share a common prefix (that is, if they are not all named `Object` + `...`), there are other ways to get the fields:

```
.Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(MyObject))
```

yields only the fields whose type is `MyObject`.

---

You could also create an attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public sealed class FieldIWantToSetAttribute : Attribute { }
```

and apply that to all fields you want to set, e.g.

```
public class Logic
{
    [FieldIWantToSet] public MyObject Object001; // will be set
    [FieldIWantToSet] public MyObject Foo;  // will be set
    public MyObject Bar;  // will not be set
}
```

Then, change the `Where` to

```
.Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<FieldIWantToSet>() != null)
```

---

<sub>Please however note that 1. you should definitely use caching. Reflection without caching is expensive, and 2. please overthink your design - why exactly do you feel the need to expose 200 fields for every other class to see?</sub>

Comment: this code unfortunately did not work for me... it supposes having all my objects named with the suffix "Object", which must not be always so. Moreover, I would also need a way to get the name of the object and to create the event handler... I would never have expected this to be a so complicated issue! thanks a lot anyway for your trials!

Comment: @anna There are other ways to only get the fields you want to. We can put anything in the `Where`. For that and for the event handler, please see my edited answer and let me know if it helped.

Comment: thanks a lot; all these comments were at the end very clarifying, but i had to accept an other answer as a solution, because it was a bit more "compact" and ready-to-use in my situation. Really thanks anyway!